# how to get the http connection in any j2ee container

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

traditional way to handle the http request in j2ee is creating a servlet and get the HttpServletRequest. Container will release the http connection after doGet/doPost.

I need a way to get the connection, and after method processing over, container wouldn't close the http connection, seperate the connection from the thread. So I can manage these connection, and determine the time to send response.

Sorry for my poor English  ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`async` servlets.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm) Then you can detach the request and response objects and manage them yourself. You can make a servlet async by:

- annotation: `@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/asyncservlet"}, asyncSupported=true)`
- web.xml:

  ```
  < servlet>
       < description>xxx</description>
       < servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name>
       < servlet-class>com.xxx.yyy</servlet-class>
       < async-supported>true</async-supported> 
  < /servlet>
  ```

The detaching happens when you start the *async context* on the request object. See the linked oracle tutorial

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I want  ^^